# AVAudioPlayer volume is low (How to set volume from speaker)

Tags: iphone, ios7, avaudioplayer

I use AVAudioPlayer for playing sounds but when playing, the sound volume is very low.

I done a search and found many codes about adding session property or session category but I'm wondering how to use it.

```
-(void) playVoice: (NSString *) path
{
    if([path isEqualToString:@""] == NO)
    {
        //Initialize the AVAudioPlayer.
        NSData *soundData= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
                      audioPlayer.delegate = self;
            NSLog(@"total time=%f", self.audioPlayer.currentTime);
            self.PlayStatusSlider.maximumValue= audioPlayer.duration;
            myTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeAudioProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];


            [audioPlayer play];
        }
    }else{
        //  NSLog(@"ErrorDownloading");
    }
}

- (void) configureAVAudioSession
{
    //get your app's audioSession singleton object
    AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    //error handling
    BOOL success;
    NSError* error;

    //set the audioSession category.
    //Needs to be Record or PlayAndRecord to use audioRouteOverride:

    success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                             error:&error];

    if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error setting category:%@",error);

    //set the audioSession override
    success = [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                         error:&error];
    if (!success)  NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort:%@",error);

    //activate the audio session
    success = [session setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
    else NSLog(@"audioSession active");
}
```

but it is not working for me. Witch part is wrong? How should I use it?

Comment: Is the sound actually coming out of the loudspeaker, or out of the receiver? Have you tested the clip elsewhere to ensure the sound level is sufficiently high? Is the system volume set to an appropriate level? There is no (public) way to programmatically control system volume, and system volume is modulated against the volume of the AVAudioPlayer, so that might be causing your low output level.

Comment: I am using emulator.I played it on the player and the volume was good but when I play it with app on the emulator the volume is low.

Comment: You should test this on a device. The simulator may behave differently than a device, and you may find this to be a non-issue.

Comment: I do not think it be related to simulator. Because I run other apps in my simulator that play sounds with high volume

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your audio session to default to speaker.
To anyone coming across this question now:

private var configureAudioSessionError: NSError?

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
  try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
  try audioSession.setActive(true)

 } catch let error as NSError {
   configureAudioSessionError = error
 }
```